# Listbox bound to ObservableCollection empty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have the following xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Retail_Utilities.Dialogs.AdjustPriceDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Name="Adjust_Price"
    Title="Adjust Price" Background="#ee0e1c64" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Height="330" Width="570" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

<Grid Height="300" Width="550">
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,110,35,60" Name="lstReasons" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=reasons}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=POS_Price_Change_Reason}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the relevant c#:

```
namespace Retail_Utilities.Dialogs
{
public partial class AdjustPriceDialog : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Twr_POS_Price_Change_Reason> reasons; ...
```

and finally, here is the code from another page that opens this window:

```
AdjustPriceDialog apd = new AdjustPriceDialog();
apd.Owner = (Window)this.Parent;
apd.reasons = new ObservableCollection<Twr_POS_Price_Change_Reason>();
var pcr = from pc in ctx.Twr_POS_Price_Change_Reasons where pc.Deactivated_On == null select pc;
foreach (Twr_POS_Price_Change_Reason pc in pcr)
{
    apd.reasons.Add(pc);
}
apd.AdjustingDetail = (Twr_POS_Invoice_Detail)lstDetails.SelectedItem;
if (apd.ShowDialog() == true)
{

}
```

When the dialog box opens, my lstReasons list is empty.  I don't get any errors and when I place a stop in the code, I see that the reasons collection gets populated with the items from the table.

Comment: Do you have change notification on your reasons property? You could also set a breakpoint on the `get` of that property to see when its being referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasons needs to be a Property (add `{ get; set;}` ). Also, look at Visual Studio Output - it shows Binding errors, there should be some info about failed binding to reasons.

Comment: I knew it had to be a simple fix, because I was doing the same thing on another page with no problems.  Thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 0):

<del>It seems your binding path is set to `POS_Price_Change_Reason`, while the name of your property is `reasons`. Unless you didn't include `POS_Price_Change_Reason` in your example code and `reasons` is the backing field for this property.</del>

Also, keep in mind that you can *only* bind to public **properties**, not fields. Additionally, if you change the value of the property, you need to notify the view of this change, by invoking your `PropertyChangedEventHandler` event for that property:

```
PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("YourPropertyName"));
```

Comment: The code binds to `reasons` in the `ItemsSource` property. The binding to `POS_Price_Change_Reason` tries to bind to a property on the `Twr_POS_Price_Change_Reason` class.

Comment: You're right, I read that over a bit too quickly. The remainder of my advice should still hold though.

Comment: adding {get;set;} to the definition of reasons was all that was needed (changing it to a property from a field).  No need to invoke propertychanged in this case, because `ObservableCollection`s do that internally, I believe.

Comment: That is true when you add/remove items in the collection. But if you change the binding of the collection *itself* (that is, change the object `reasons` points to), you need to call `PropertyChanged("reasons")`.

Comment: ah, I see.  Thanks.  I'll keep that in mind as I go.  This is my first enterprise class .NET project, so I'm getting a lot of OJT.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be How you are creating the property.
I know you put your prperty as an observable collection but this doesn't mean it is by it self observalble!
so you need to notify the UI when this property is changed by doing something in the setter like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Twr_POS_Price_Change_Reason> reasons
{
get{....}
set
{
Notify('reasons')
}
}
```

I don't remember the exact code because I didn't use WPF for a while but it is a method in INotifyPropertyChanged, good luck!